# How to query two SQL tables and filter that data

Tags: sql, database, oracle-apex

I'm trying to gather data from two tables like this

```
SELECT table1.NAME, table2.NAME
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.NAME = table2.NAME
```

then i want to be able to query that output data with a new SQL statement is there a way of doing that?

Comment: I think you want data from two tables where a particular value is the same... Google Inner join?

Comment: Selecting the same joined column from both tables is only going to produce two columns with identical duplicate values. You probably want to select from table1 where it exists in table2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use a CTE:

```
with cte as
(SELECT table1.NAME, table2.NAME
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.NAME = table2.NAME)
select * from cte --here goes your statement
```

Please note that you should be using the modern explicit join syntax instead of the old one you're using:

```
with cte as
(SELECT table1.NAME, table2.NAME
FROM table1 inner join table2
on table1.NAME = table2.NAME)
select * from cte --here goes your statement
```